# mongodb inserting inspite of a document with a specific name being present

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have this following piece of code

```
        coll_name = "#{some_name}_#{differentiator}"
        coll_object = @database[coll_name]
        idExist = coll_object.find({"adSet.name" => NAME}).first()
        if idExist.nil?
            docId = coll_object.insert(request)
        else
            docId = idExist["_id"]
        end
        return docId
```

differentiator can be the same or different from the Loop that is code is called.So everytime there can be a new collection or same collection.Now if the same collection is recieved then there might be an object with name = NAME. In that case no insert should be carried out.However i have observed that documents with the same NAME are getting inserted.Can anybody helpout on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for this behavior could be a race condition: The duplicate is inserted by another thread/process between line 3 and 5 of your application. Two threads try to create the same name at the same time, the database returns for both that the name doesn't exist yet, and when those replies arrived, both insert the document.

To prevent this from happening, [create an unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) on the name-field. This will prevent MongoDB from inserting two documents with the same name. When you do this, you could remove the check for existence before inserting. Just try to insert the document, and then call getLastError to find out if it worked. When it didn't, retrieve the existing document with an additional query.

Comment: The thing is this is a single process and no threading is involved at all.Can there be some other reason why this might be happening.

Comment: @nnm When you use non-safe write concern and you insert documents in fast succession, an insert might not have been processed yet when you search for it shortly afterwards. But really, when you want to enforce uniqueness for certain values, use an unique index.

Comment: I tried adding coll_object.create_index([["adSet.name", Mongo::GEO2D]]) and also coll_object.ensure_index([["adSet.name", Mongo::GEO2D]]) and then purposely inserting document with the same name.It does not throw any exception and stores all the duplicates as well.I tried adding sleep of 5 seconds also to avoid second insertion before first gets over.But still duplicates persist.Why?

Comment: inshort how do i do this in ruby db.duplicate_collection.ensureIndex({'duplicate_key' : 1},{unique: true, dropDups: true})

Comment: @nnm Take a look at [the documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#ensure_index-instance_method). The ensureIndex method has a second parameter "opts". Also, why do you try to create a *geo2d* index? Your name is a string, not a pair of GPS coordinates.

Comment: @nnm I think you should create a second question asking about how to create unique indexes on a string field with the Ruby MongoDB driver.